# how to store date default model value in mongoose model in dd-mm-yyyy:hh:mm:ss:sss

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, datetime

Below is the sample  mongoose model

```
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
      CatId:{ type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
      Name : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      Description : String,
      Is_Active:Number,
      Db_Created_TimeStamp:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
      Db_Updated_TimeStamp:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
  },{collection: "Categories"})
categorySchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
mongoose.model('Categories',categorySchema);
```

where the Db_Created_TimeStamp is taking default current time stamp in format "2017-11-19T02:38:42.233+0000"

How to store the date format in dd-mm-yyyy:hh:mm:ss:sss in IST format

Not sure the difference between IST and ISO format please suggest a way to accomplish

Comment: try to take a look at moment.js

Comment: You should still _store_ using an ISODate and _format_ that date on output (aka "in your application") according to your needs.